# Does alum heal canker sores (mouth ulcers)

Tags: medical-science

I've read different accounts of alum working like magic in healing mouth ulcers, but still it seem pretty anecdotal. However, there's numerous accounts of people saying that they apply alum, and that the ulcer disappear after 24 hours.

Any reason to trust this or not?

Comment: I'd love to see an answer for this. I can't find any research on the subject, but it may be that I'm not looking in the right place.

Comment: As a mouth ulcer sufferer, I did an extensive search on the internet as well as consulting my doctor. The conclusions were..
Avoid sodium laurel sulfate in toothpaste, shampoo and washing-up liquid.
Check your B12 levels.
Take lysine tablets to shorten the healing time.